# ZSH uses 100% CPU on ubuntu

Tags: zsh, terminator

I am using ZSH with terminator, however all the time zsh is using 100% and i can't find what is causing this problem.

ZSH installed plugins: zsh-autosuggestions

Answer (score 1):

Use `top` or `htop` to see what process ID is at 100%. You could try installing `ltrace` and run `ltrace -p <PID_at_100%CPU>` to trace its library calls. If you see a particular string or function reappear, search for that string in your .zshrc and plug-ins.

(I've experienced this high CPU but I'm using an advanced prompt, [pure](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/), so [my issue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/issues/502) probably isn't yours.)